# Expressjs Deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Errors

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running into two errors when I try to run `eb start` and `eb status --verbose`. I tried googling the issues, but couldn't find any solutions. Am I missing aws packages? I am deploying expressjs Here are my errors:

`eb start`

****FIXED by Install pip Boto*****

Error:

```
Starting application "my-app".
Would you like to deploy the latest Git commit to your environment? [y/n]: y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.createapplicationversion", line 20, in <module>
    from aws.dev_tools import *
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/my-app/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line 5, in <module>
    import boto
ImportError: No module named boto
Cannot run aws.push for local repository HEAD:
```

`eb status --verbose`

Error:

```
Retrieving status of environment "loyola-venture-community".
ValidationError. 1 validation error detected: Value '[loyola-venture-community]' at 'environmentNames' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 23, Member must have length greater than or equal to 4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to [Install Boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html) to fix your first issue. After you do that, run the `eb status --verbose` again and see what error comes up and update your question.

Regarding the second error, the environment name `loyola-venture-community` is 24 characters which is past the limit of 23. Shorten it and that API call will work.

Comment: Hey @Josh Davis, thank you, your solution helped fix my first problem, but I am still receiving the second error message. Any thoughts as to how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does the name of your environment include those brackets? If so, try without it.

Comment: The name actually doesn't contain those brackets, it is just how the error message displays them.

Comment: Ahh, well it looks like the name of your environment has changed since I last saw it ;) Before it was `'[my-app]'` (which obviously fit the constraints) and now it is `'[loyola-venture-community]'`. If that is the true name of the environment, the length of `loyola-venture-community` is 24 characters, which would explain the error you are getting. Shorten it by a few characters to fix that.